# How to give different subComponent on Expanding different rows in React-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-table

Have used Expander in one column of React-table. On expanding a different row of table i want to display different subComponents. My subComponent has another react-table. So the issue is when two rows are expanded , the subComponent react table gets the data source acc to the 2nd row and thus it updates the same in the 1st row subComponent as well. I want to have different data sources according to the row.

Also tell how to give Column accessor value with the Expander button in the same cell.

I have given the data dynamically to the subComponent react table that is doin fine.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use React.CreateElement and pass your SubComponent And Separete Store (if exists)

for more information about creating dynamic component see [React Site](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html)